# kitchen faucet is stuck and we need help

Tags: kitchens, sink

my husband is trying to remove a kitchen sink at his parents house. it is a three piece faucet. the handle to turn the water on is being held on by some gold clamp. it is in the shape of a pac man with 5 or so holes it. what could thus be and how do we get it off

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: I could not figure out how to post picture. do you know how?

Comment: Isn't there a nut holding that pac-man-washer on? Add pics with those little buttons at the top; click edit.

Comment: @seneira Just take a picture with your smart phone and then edit your post, click the photo button, and browse to your picture!

Comment: unfortunately their is no area to add a photo I even downloaded the app. but their is no nut. this gold piece is actually attached to the sink

Comment: Sounds like a C-clip or E-clip, but can't be sure without seeing it...

Comment: Please put your photo(s) on a file-sharing site (imgr, flickr etc), make sure it is visible without a login and post the URL in a comment here, some helpful person will edit it into your question for you.

Comment: thank you so much everyone. we never figured out what the piece was. but we took a saw to the faucet and got it off that way.

Answer (score 4):

In my part of the world, typical tap clamps look like this

[image]

or this

[image]

Sometimes, things are obscured by a tap brace that you must remove.

[image]

The retaining nuts are not always easy to see in the darkness under a kitchen sink full of pipes and other obstructions.

But if you are removing the sink and tap and disposing of both, it doesn't matter.

You can undo the other end of the tap tailpipes and throw out the whole lot. In the worst case you can cut through the pipes (above the isolating valves obviously) with a suitable saw and tidy up later.

Comment: it was close to this but at small holes in it with no visible screws

Answer (score 0):

Just to add other options (and I'm not sure these fit your situation).

1. Use a sink wrench:  eg:

http://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/i/spin/image/spin_prod_225594201?hei=520&wid=520&op_sharpen=1

2. Use a sawzall to cut the faucet off right above the sink (my neighbor used this method with a very difficult faucet).

Comment: In my locale, these wrenches are referred to as a "basin wrench".